# Get records as per the given ids' mysql

Tags: mysql

This is the query i am executing

```
SELECT email,firstname,lastname FROM `sco_customer` 
WHERE id_customer IN (7693,7693,7693,7693,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,7693,3,3,3,3,3,7693,7693,3,3,3,7693,3,3,3)
```

This gives me only two records as their are same number of id_customer is filtered i.e 7693,3

```
email   firstname   lastname
abc@any.com Test    Mage
abc2@any.com    User    Mage
```

It should give the same number of records as much is the `id_customer`

Any thoughts how this can be achieved ?

Comment: Why you want duplicate results?

Comment: Due to some issues with logic in looping

Comment: You must convert your IDs list to row source (i.e. not in WHERE but as a table in FROM).

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: Adminer 4.7.5 4.7.7

Comment: Where are these IN values coming from ? Are there any tables having these values already ?@newphpdev

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query, but note that issues of data display are often best resolved in application code

Answer (score 0):

The following statement should solve you problem:

```
SELECT email,firstname,lastname FROM `sco_customer` 
join (select 7693 as id_customer union all 
select 7693 union all
select 7693 union all 
select 3 union all  
select 3 union all  
select 3    
) tmp on sco_customer.id_customer = tmp.id_customer
```

Comment: This will work for only one id 7693 i  willl have lots of ids

Comment: @newphpdev No it also works for other id's if you add a line `select 3 from union all`. Where the id's come from?

Comment: I mean what if i have multiple id data's like (7693,7693,7693,7693,3,3,3,3) ?

Comment: @newphpdev then expand the list: `SELECT email,firstname,lastname FROM sco_customer 
join (select 7693 as id_customer union all 
select 7693 union all
select 7693 union all 
select 7693 union all 
select 3 union all 
select 3 union all 
select 3 
) tmp on sco_customer.id_customer = tmp.id_customer`

Comment: Cool thanks can you update according to it ? Actually i am fetching values for some id's only thats why i had used "IN" mysql function.

Answer (score 0):

Try below.  Instead of `WHERE` clause you can generate a dummy table and join it with your main table.(`WITH` works for version 8 or above)

```
WITH SAMPLE AS 
(
SELECT 7693 AS ID FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS ID FROM DUAL
)
SELECT email,firstname,lastname FROM `sco_customer`
INNER JOIN SAMPLE ON SAMPLE.ID=ID_CUSTOMER
```

Below mysql version 8:

```
SELECT email,firstname,lastname FROM `sco_customer`
INNER JOIN (
SELECT 7693 AS ID FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS ID FROM DUAL
)SAMPLE ON SAMPLE.ID=ID_CUSTOMER
```

Comment: This will work for only one id 7693 i  willl have lots of ids

Comment: Nope it will work all of your `SCO_CUSTOMER.ID_CUSTOMER` if it matches. If there is no id of 3 it will not work. For you to do is using left join instead of inner join but your question here is different. So it will work trust me.

Comment: I mean what if i have multiple id data's like (7693,7693,7693,7693,3,3,3,3) ?

Comment: Then you should add the same values you want and expand your dummy table with those. @newphpdev